# Custom Ruby on Rails action redirects to local host no matter what

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wanted to create a new action in one of my controllers, but it doesn't matter what I write into the action it just redirects to localhost.

In my routes.rb:

```
match '/save_last_updated' => 'forum_topics#save_last_updated'
```

In forum_topics_controller.rb

```
def save_last_updated
  //I tried here everything, raise error, redirect, render, but none of them work.
end
```

And even the console didn't help much:

```
Processing by ForumTopicsController#save_last_updated as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 24.8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

My overall goal would be to call that action with a jquery ajax request so that the action updated the database.

Comment: Check if you have any `before_filter`s enabled, maybe authorisation-related, that can cause a redirect. Looks like your action doesn't even get executed.

Comment: Seems like you have some `before_filter` setup in the controller. Can you please ensure that?